# JavaBeans: What's the difference between an attribute and a property?

Tags: java, properties, attributes, javabeans

In the JavaBean section of my revision list it states that I should know "the difference between an attribute and a property". I can't really find a difference between the two. I'm aware that JavaBeans use properties and normal Java classes use attributes (or at least that's what I was taught to call them) but I can't see a real difference.

Is it to do with getter/setter methods?

Thanks

Comment: hint: read the description of the properties tag you just used.

Comment: Meanwhile you will have found, that **attribute** is simply a class field, and a **property** an named abstraction with a getter (is..., get...) and setter (set...). In the newest bean specs a public attribute may function as a property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Examples

#### Property and attribute are equivalent

```
private int age;

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

#### Property `age` translates to `personAge` attribute

```
private int personAge;

public int getAge() {
    return personAge;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.personAge = age;
}
```

#### Property is synthesized, there is no attribute

In this case the property is read-only:

```
private int age;
private Sex sex;

public boolean isFemaleAdult() {
    return sex == Sex.FEMALE && age >= 18
}
```

I found few intereseting hints in [Tapestry documentation](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry3/doc/DevelopersGuide/beans.properties.html):

> A property is not the same as an attribute ... though, most often, each property is backed up by an attribute.

and later:

> Another common pattern is a synthesized property. Here, there is no real attribute at all, the value is always computed on the fly.

Answer (score 4):

In broad terms, properties corresponds to method pairs `atype getXXX()`/`void setXXX(atype )`. Attributes refer to member fields.